# Optimal number of database connections (node-mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

By default, node-mysql limits the maximum number of mysql connections in a connection pool to 10.  This seems pretty conservative to me.

Is there an optimal number of connections I should set it to?  ( is there a number beyond which performance is likely to degrade, instead of increasing? )

Thanks

Comment: That completely depends on your server and network environment, and on your usage patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no optimal configuration for maximum number of connections, and you shouldn't need to touch it unless there are noticeable bottlenecks in your application. The number of connections you require can vary on how your application is structured, your system's performance, and your network throughput.